# How to make .slideToggle stop detaching itself

Tags: jquery, css

so when I press a button, my slideToggle activates, but it detaches itself from the button that has the slideToggle activation. Here is a JSFiddle of the code: http://jsfiddle.net/3Ubr9/1/

You'll see it when you press on the "Information" button.

HTML

```
                        <button type="button" class="firstButton">Information</button>
            <div class="firstHidden" style="display:none">
                <p>This is a 1965 chevy camaro</p>
            </div>
```

JS

```
             $(".firstButton").on('click', function(){
    $(".firstHidden").stop().slideToggle();
          })
```

CSS

```
                 div {
                  background-color:blue;
               width:200px;
             height:200px;

                   }
```

Comment: Hey, what do you mean by detaching? The jump of space in between the elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you have a `p` element in your div, and your default stylesheet appends a top margin to it to separate it from preceding content.  You can remove the margin with CSS:

```
div.firstHidden p {
    margin-top: 0px;
}
```

See JS fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3Ubr9/2/).

Comment: Ah thank you! Is the hidden 'margin-top' the reason why people use CSS Resets?

Comment: Kind of.  Most every browser will separate paragraphs from each other -- it just makes things so much more legible!  But different browsers might do it differently.  One browser might put default to putting a `margin-top: 15px;` on paragraphs, one browser might instead do a `padding-top: 20px;`

The browsers were written by different people who had different opinions about the best way to present things.  CSS resets aim to make it so that each browser will display items in as close to the same exact way as possible -- that way, the content will look the same no matter what browser you're using

Comment: See here for a more in-depth explanation of browser resets and why they exist:

http://meyerweb.com/eric/thoughts/2007/04/18/reset-reasoning/